# Razor: <text></text> inside lambda

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The following snippet gives me an error:

```
@foreach (PageViewModel root in menuData)
    {
        Action < PageViewModel > traverse = null;
        traverse = (n) => {
            @<text>
                <li><a href="@n.Url">@n.Title</a></li>
            </text>
            n.Children.ForEach(traverse);
        };
        traverse(root);
    }
```

The error is: `CS1002: ; expected`, right on the line after the `</text>` closing tag.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't think you need the @ before text - `@<text>` should be `<text>`?

Comment: nope, gives me a CS1525: Invalid expression term '<'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try making your code snippet into a [Templated Razor Delegate](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx).

Based on Phil Haack's example, you could make a helper that looked something like:

```
public static class RazorExtensions 
{
    public static HelperResult Traverse(this Action<PageViewMoidel> traverse, 
        Func<T, HelperResult> template) 
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer => 
        {
            traverse = (n) => template(n).WriteTo(writer);
        });
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer:* I haven't tested this and have conveniently omitted the call to `n.Children.Foreach` for simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
@foreach (var root in menuData)
{
    foreach (var child in root.Children)
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@child.Url">@child.Title</a>
        </li>
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is interested in using a lambda.  I'm sure the example is just simplified.